# C# LINQ order by error

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

Hei,
i think order by is ordering things wrongly. Example code:

```
static void Main()
{            
    // Create a delicious data source.
    string[] fruits = { "äax", "ääü", "äbü" };

    // Query for ascending sort.
    IEnumerable<string> sortAscendingQuery =
        from fruit in fruits
        orderby fruit //"ascending" is default
        select fruit;       

    // Execute the query.
    Console.WriteLine("Ascending:");
    foreach (string s in sortAscendingQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
Ascending:
ääü
äax
äbü
```

The right order should be:
äax
äbu
ääü

Anybody encountered this error before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This linq returns the correct results - you need specify the string comparison to use.

```
foreach (string s in fruits.OrderBy(s=>s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

That's going to use the default implementation of `IComparer<string>`. That's a culture-sensitive comparison, which I believe is why it's deeming "ääü" as coming before "äax".

Were you expecting an ordinal comparison? If so, you can specify the comparer explicitly, but not in a query expression:

```
IEnumerable<string> sortAscendingQuery = fruits
    .OrderBy(fruit => fruit, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

If that's not what you're looking for, please explain what sort of comparison you need.

Comment: The string why i use to order by can vary from numerical value to alphapedical or both together.. What comparison i should use in this case?

Comment: @hs2d: That entirely depends on how you want to compare strings. You may well want to provide your own implementation of `IComparer<string>` which you can pass in as the second argument to `OrderBy`.

Comment: @hs2d: you should use the one that sorts correctly for the users of your application. You're the only person here who knows what that is!

Comment: @Eric: I need to sort them aphabedically

Comment: @hs2d: You need to define "alphabetically" when it comes to things like accented characters - and different cultures typically treat those differently. Also, a pure lexicographic ordering will put "100" ahead of "20" - is that okay for you?

Comment: I think i found what i was looking for, example:
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("et");
var result = fruits.OrderBy(f => f, StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
Now i just have to figure out how to use this instead linq query.